# Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I am using https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver to implement Elasticsearch with Laravel Scout. Ivan mentions this on Github:

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Mapping types will be completely removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.0.

If I understood right here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html I either need to use:

1. `PUT index?include_type_name=true`

or, better:

2)

```
PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "foo": "baz"
}
```

I am stuck since I have no idea how to use either 1) or 2)

How can I add the parameter `include_type_name=true`?

How can I create the right mapping without using the `include_type_name` parameter?

```
class TestIndexConfigurator extends IndexConfigurator
{
    use Migratable;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $settings = [
    ];
    protected $name = 'test';
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this plugin i mean do you want search a `User` by his name for example?

Comment: have you found any solution for it?

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch It's easier to use than `babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver `

Answer (score 21):

Earlier versions of Elasticsearch (<= 5) supported multiple types per index. That meant that you could have different data mappings for each type. With Elasticsearch 6, this was removed and you can only have single mapping type.

Therefore, for Elasticsearch 7 (latest release), you can add an index, setup mappings and add document like this:

- Create an index

  ```
  PUT user
  ```
- Add mapping

  ```
  PUT user/_mapping 
  {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "loginCount": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Add document(s)

  ```
  PUT user/_doc/1
  {
    "name": "John",
    "loginCount": 4
  }
  ```
- Check data in the index

  ```
  GET user/_search
  ```

Now, regarding the scout-elasticsearch-driver that you use, after reading the documentation you mentioned, it is simply saying that you need to create separate index configurator for each searchable model, as multiple models cannot be stored inside the same index.

So to create the index, run

`php artisan make:index-configurator MyIndexConfigurator`

and then

`php artisan elastic:create-index App\\MyIndexConfigurator`

which will create the index in the elasticsearch for you.

To learn more about elasticsearch, I suggest you install both elasticsearch and kibana to your development machine and then play around with it in kibana - the interface is quite nice and supports autocomplete to ease the learning curve.

Answer (score 7):

When I tried `GET product/default/_mapping` in Kibana console.

I kept getting this error.

> "Types cannot be provided in get mapping requests, unless
>   include_type_name is set to true"

This is happening in elastic search 7.3.0. 
Looks like the above command is no longer supported in latest versions of elastic search.

It worked for me when I remove the default from the above command.

```
GET product/_mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

I getting same error like "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true"

you have to add "include_type_name:true" inside the object

fix this problem above code

```
let type = true

return await esClient.indices.putMapping({
    index:indexName,
    type:mappingType,
    body:mapping,
    include_type_name:type
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PUT busloggw4/_doc/_mapping?include_type_name=true
{
  "properties": {
    "log_flag": {
      "type":"long"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add text to explain this answer better? E.g. what's going on, and why this code should work?